# gson use annotation to exclude superclass's field

Tags: java, android, gson

When I use some ORM library,such as LitePal
it ask me to extend it's Class `DataSupport`,and when I using Gson to transform my POJO to JSON string,it get

```
{
    "age": 25,
    "sex": false,
    "height": 178,
    "username": "test",
    "weight": 65,
    "associatedModelsMapForJoinTable": {},
    "associatedModelsMapWithFK": {},
    "associatedModelsMapWithoutFK": {},
    "baseObjId": 2,
    "listToClearAssociatedFK": [],
    "listToClearSelfFK": []
}
```

by I just need subclass(it's my POJO-User)' field,such as:

```
{
    "age": 25,
    "sex": false,
    "height": 178,
    "weight": 65,
    "username": "test"
}
```

my Gson version is v2.7

```
compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.7'
```

here is `DataSupport`'s field

```
/**
 * The identify of each model. LitePal will generate the value
 * automatically. Do not try to assign or modify it.
 */
private long baseObjId;

/**
 * A map contains all the associated models' id with M2O or O2O
 * associations. Each corresponding table of these models contains a foreign
 * key column.
 */
private Map<String, Set<Long>> associatedModelsMapWithFK;

/**
 * A map contains all the associated models' id with M2O or O2O association.
 * Each corresponding table of these models doesn't contain foreign key
 * column. Instead self model has a foreign key column in the corresponding
 * table.
 */
private Map<String, Long> associatedModelsMapWithoutFK;

/**
 * A map contains all the associated models' id with M2M association.
 */
private Map<String, Set<Long>> associatedModelsMapForJoinTable;

/**
 * When updating a model and the associations breaks between current model
 * and others, if current model holds a foreign key, it need to be cleared.
 * This list holds all the foreign key names that need to clear.
 */
private List<String> listToClearSelfFK;

/**
 * When updating a model and the associations breaks between current model
 * and others, clear all the associated models' foreign key value if it
 * exists. This list holds all the associated table names that need to
 * clear.
 */
private List<String> listToClearAssociatedFK;

/**
 * A list holds all the field names which need to be updated into default
 * value of model.
 */
private List<String> fieldsToSetToDefault;
```

here is my POJO class's field

```
public class User extends DataSupport {
    public static final String TAG = User.class.getSimpleName();
    @SerializedName("username")
    private String userName = "";
    @SerializedName("sex")
    private boolean female = false;
    @SerializedName("age")
    private int age = UserDataUtil.DEFAULT_AGE;
    @SerializedName("height")
    private int height = UserDataUtil.DEFAULT_HEIGHT;
    @SerializedName("weight")
    private int weight = UserDataUtil.DEFAULT_WEIGHT;
```

how can I exclude supperclass `DataSupport`'s field by using Gson's annotation

when I using `GsonBuilder.serExclusionStrategies` such as

```
.setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                    if (f.getDeclaringClass() == DataSupport.class) {
                        String fName = f.getName();
                        if (fName.equals("associatedModelsMapForJoinTable")
                                || fName.equals("associatedModelsMapWithFK")
                                || fName.equals("associatedModelsMapWithoutFK")
                                || fName.equals("baseObjId")
                                || fName.equals("listToClearAssociatedFK")
                                || fName.equals("listToClearSelfFK")) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                    return false;
                }
            })
```

It does work, but I just want to know could I solve the same problem with and only use Gson's annotation if possible.

But I don't want to use `@Expose` in every field of subclass, I just want want to exclude superclass's field by using `@Expose` annotation in supperclass.

I try the way life follow,but it dosen't work:

```
public class DataSupport {

/**
 * The identify of each model. LitePal will generate the value
 * automatically. Do not try to assign or modify it.
 */
@Expose(serialize = false,deserialize = false)
private long baseObjId;
```

my english is poor,if my description is confusing you,please let me know and I will try to correct it,thanks

Comment: Did you implement the setter and getter method ?

Answer (score 0):

Easy, use *transient* in the field's definition, for example:

```
private transient Map<String, Set<Long>> associatedModelsMapWithFK;
```

Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md).

Comment: I wonder if  `transient` would make some influence to ORM library? I perfer to use annotation

Comment: With OrmLite for android there is no problem: just tested it and worked as desired. But it depends on the specs of your ORM library. If you really want annotations you could make your own annotation and adapt it to the exclusion strategy you made. This would be a more generic approach, but just using transient will save a lot of time.